# How to add the elements of a list to a hashtable?

Tags: list, ocaml, hashtable

I'm trying to add elements to my hashtable by using a list.

I have a node type like the following :

```
type position = float * float
type node = position
```

I wrongfully assumed and started to write my function as if I could apply the same method of recursively building a normal list, but I don't know where to put my recursive call now.

This is what I've tried so far :

```
let init_dist nodes source =
  let hshNodes = Hashtbl.create (List.length nodes) + 5 in
  let rec init_dist_aux nodes hashtable source =
  match nodes with
  | [] -> hashtable
  | x::tl > if x = source then Hashtbl.add hashtable (x,0.)
            else Hashtbl.add hashtable (x,max_float)
```

The `nodes` argument is a list of node, `source` is a node.

I have no error output because I didn't run this due to the fact that it just couldn't work.

My goal is to be able to write a function that allows me to add bindings to my hashtbl using a list of node. \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems fine. I don't see any recursive call to `init_dist_aux`, so it will stop after adding the first element. Also it will generate a type error  since one branch of your `match` returns a hash table and the other returns unit (`()`).

Adding the recursive call should fix both of these problems.

**Update**

You have this right now:

```
if x = source then
    Hashtbl.add hashtable (x,0.)
else
    Hashtbl.add hashtable (x,max_float)
```

What you want to have is this:

```
if x = source then
    Hashtbl.add hashtable x 0.
else
    Hashtbl.add hashtable x max_float;
init_dist_aux tl hashtable source
```

With this change, your `init_dist_aux` function already returns a hash table. There's nothing special to do to get this to happen.

But note that I don't see a call to `init_dist_aux` anywhere. You definitely need to call it to get things to work :-)

(As a side comment, if the code for `init_dist_aux` isn't fairly obvious to you you might need to spend a little more time thinking about recursion. Just a humble observation.)

Comment: Where should I put the recursive call please? Other question, is there a way to have this function be a type hashtable? In other words, have it return a hashtable?

Comment: I have this function now :
```let init_dist nodes source =
let hshNodes = Hashtbl.create ((List.length nodes) + 5) in
  let rec init_dist_aux nodes hsh source =
    match nodes with
    | [] -> hsh
    | x::tl -> if x = source then Hashtbl.add hsh (x,0.)
               else
                 Hashtbl.add hsh (x,max_float);
                 init_dist_aux tl hsh source
  in init_dist_aux nodes hshNodes source```
However I have this error now : ```This expression has type 'a -> unit but an expression was expected of type unit because it is in the left-hand side of a sequence```

Comment: Your calls to `Hashtbl.add` are incorrect. You have `add (key, value)` but you should have `add key value`.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum, since OCaml 4.07<sup>1</sup> adding a list of key/value bindings to a hashtable in OCaml can be readily implemented with [sequences](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) using [`Hashtbl.add_seq`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Hashtbl.html#VALadd_seq).

```
# let ht = Hashtbl.create 1024;;
val ht : ('_weak1, '_weak2) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# let lst = [(1, 4); (5, 6); (2, 7)];;
val lst : (int * int) list = [(1, 4); (5, 6); (2, 7)]
# lst 
  |> List.to_seq 
  |> Hashtbl.add_seq ht;;
- : unit = ()
# Hashtbl.iter (Format.printf "%d: %d\n") ht;; 
2: 7
1: 4
5: 6
- : unit = ()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> OCaml 4.07 released July 10th, 2018.